# Check if some elements are present in a List in Java

Tags: java, collections

I would like to check if multiple elements are present in a list, at the same time. 
For example

```
List<Integer> output = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
```

Instead of checking for occurrence of 1,2 and 3 in the list as

```
output.contains(1);
output.contains(2);
output.contains(3);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to check for all elements in a single line.

Comment: Use `containsAll`

Comment: The first step is always to [check the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: Did't the search engine of your choice lead you to the public and free [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)

Comment: Do you want to check if at  least one element or all element ? you have a conflict between the title and the post please update

Comment: Your three distinct contains() invocations yield three distinct responses.  Assuming that by "single line" you actually mean "single invocation of one single method" (which is a different thing), you would get one single response.  You haven't specified how you expect that single response to represent the same semantics as the three distinct responses you get from the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (output.containsAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))) {
  // Your Code 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in Java for it. It's called `containsAll()` Take in mind that under the hood it's not faster than calling `contains()` for each of the elements. The algorithm speed is approximately O(n*m) where n and m are the sizes of both collections.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list for the elements which you wish yo check and then do

```
    List<Integer> output = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
    List<Integer> results = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        if (output.containsAll(results)) {
          //do stuff
        }
```